# Negative Active Tasks in Spark UI under load (Max number of executor failed)

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

[image]I am running a spark streaming application on Spark 1.5.0 in CDH 5.5.0.  In the logs I see max number of executor failed.  I am unable to find the root cause.

We are getting this issue intermittently every other day.Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 11, (reason: Max number of executor failures reached)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug, you can track changes in following tickets:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5098,
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10141,
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2319

Edit: about this message "Max number of executors failed" - Spark have parameter [`spark.yarn.max.executor.failures`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html). By default 2x number of executors, minimum 3. If there were more failures than it was set in this parameter, then application will be killed.

You can change value of this parameter. However I would be worried why you have so many executor failures - maybe you've got too less memory? Or bug in code? Without code and/or context information we are not able to help in investigation about potential bug

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt response Gaweda.  I am getting this max number of executor reached exception which is causing this failure.  I am not worried much about UI but worried about max number of executor reached exception mentioned above.

Comment: Title suggested that this is main issue ;) Please add some logs and context information, then we will be able to help you :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help really appreciate.  I will draft another question soon.